# How to find total revenue for last 30 days transaction in sql vba?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I have table structure as

```
Tran_ID | total_amt | tran_date
```

I need to find total revenue generated in last 30 days of transactions.

I used below mentioned query But it is neither giving any result nor any error.

```
select sum(total_amt)
from Transactions 
having tran_date between max(tran_date)-30 and max(tran_date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sub query.

```
SELECT sum(total_amt) as total from Transactions as a left join
(SELECT 'a' as gr, max(tran_date) as dmax, max(tran_date)-30 as dmin
FROM Transactions) as b
on a.tran_date <=b.dmax and a.tran_date>= b.dmin
where not isnull(b.dmax)
group by b.gr
```

Comment: I need to get above result only for customers aged between 20 to 25. There is one more table "Customer" having fields CustID, DOB and customerID is foreign key in Transactions table.How to do that?

Comment: @SamidhaPrasad: What is the structure of the customer table? What is  Age field name? What fields are joining the transactions table and the customer table, respectively?

Comment: Transaction table structure : Tran_ID | total_amt | tran_date | cust_id and Customer table structure: customer_Id | DOB. I had used this query to get the transaction details of customer between certain age: "select * from Transactions as t left outer join Customer as c on t.cust_id=c.customer_Id WHERE DateDiff('yyyy', c.DOB, date()) between 28 and 35".

Comment: SELECT  sum(total_amt) as total from
(SELECT a.* , b.* from Transactions as a left join
(SELECT 'a' as gr, max(tran_date) as dmax, max(tran_date)-30 as dmin
FROM Transactions) as b
on a.tran_date <=b.dmax and a.tran_date>= b.dmin
where not isnull(b.dmax) ) as c , customer as d
where c.cust_id = d.customer_id and DateDiff('yyyy', d.DOB, date()) between 28 and 35
group by gr

Answer (score 1):

You should use a where clause instead to do the filtering. Try this:

```
select sum(a.total_amt)
from Transactions a inner join (select max(tran_date) as max_trans_date from Transactions) b
on (a.tran_date between dateadd(DD,-30,b.max_tran_date) and b.max_tran_date);
```

Comment: It shows a runtime error. (Between operator without And in query expression 'a.tran_date between dateadd(DD,-30,b.max_tran_date'

Comment: I just wrapped the join condition with brackets. Try again.

Comment: It shows an error message that "MS Office Access data engine couldn't find object max(tran_date) max_trans_date". However, i added "as". But now it shows an error "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Comment: I added an as to the alias. Try again.

Comment: dateadd(DD,-30,b.max_tran_date) and b.max_tran_date   change to dateadd('D',-30,b.max_trans_date) and b.max_trans_date